# Multiple selection for ListView in simple todo list android app not working

Tags: android, listview

I am new to Android development and am creating a simple todo list. I am trying to have my app change the background color of a particular item and keep it that background color (similar to highlighting) when I click on it. I've tried using `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)`, but that gives me a checkbox, which is not really what I want. I don't want the checkbox, and instead, want to alter the background color.

I have read many threads on stackoverflow regarding this issue, but none of them solved my issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

My TodoActivity class is:

```
package com.example.simpletodo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TodoActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<String> items;
    ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
    ListView lvItems;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo);
    lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    items.add("First Item");
    items.add("Second Item");
    setupListViewListener();
    lvItems.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items));
    lvItems.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
}

private void setupListViewListener() {
    lvItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {
            items.remove(position);
            itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
    });
}


public void addTodoItem(View v) {
    EditText etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
    itemsAdapter.add(etNewItem.getText().toString());
    etNewItem.setText("");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }
}
```

and my XML file is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:onClick="addTodoItem"
        android:text="@string/button_add" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNewItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:hint="@string/add_new_item" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've notice you are setting the adapter twice in your original code.  Only the last one matters.  The last one here gives you the checkboxes.  The first one is unable to highlight b/c to highlight you need to use the "activated" version of the simple layout, as it adds a background to the textview that changes depending whether the item is enabled/dsiabled.

Comment: @NameSpace are you referring to
`lvItems.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items));
    lvItems.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize, changing my answer, as my first one was incorrect.  Here is how you would select/highlight multiple items using a default adapter:

```
    String[] strArray = {"row1", "row2", "row3"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, strArray);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

The code above will give you highlighted selected items.  If you want checkboxes, replace with the layout below:

```
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice
```

The functions below should let you  determine which items are currently selected.

```
    lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
    lv.getCheckedItemIds();
```

For anything more complicated (e.g. customizing background colors, appearance, etc), you will need to supply a custom layout and/or override the getView() functions of your adapters.  Here's an excellent tutorial on that:  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: thanks for the information. So would the default tools be sufficient if you wanted to have checkboxes next to the items?

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Namespace, that was exactly what I was looking for! I also noticed that the default color is blue. Can I change the background color by creating a `selector` xml file with something like:

`<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_pressed="true"/></selector>`?

Comment: yes, you can write your own selector.  But then you also need to copy the source for simple_list_item_activated_1, and change the background to your new selector.  You can find the source at this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_activated_1.xml).  Then change the layout you pass to the one where you edited the source.